# It is possible to filter more than one sku when exporting products in Dataflow - Profiles?

Tags: magento-1.9, export

[image: It is possible to filter more than one sku when exporting products in Dataflow - Profiles]

Currently I can export all products which is a gigantic mass that timeout or just one product, I would like to export a selection of sku but I have tried thousands of parameters to separate the skus and not find out which parameter is right or if it is possible to export by somes select sku